# SQL filter the data if existed in the other table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm using SQL Server 2005, and I have a script like this:

```
  select INV_Nr, INV_Date, INV_Customer

  from INVOICE A, 
  left outer join CANCEL_INVOICE B on B.INV_Nr  = A.INV_Nr
```

So how can I add in 'where' clause / filter that all the INVOICE.INV_Nr that existed in CANCEL_INVOICE.INV_Nr will not show in the query result?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way([probably the best](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)), `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT inv_nr, 
       inv_date, 
       inv_customer 
FROM   invoice i 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                  FROM   cancel_invoice c 
                  WHERE  c.inv_nr = i.inv_nr)
```

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` approach might work but is less efficient and leads to incorrect (or at least unexpected) results, since there is no way to differentiate between a row that doesn't exist and a row that does exist but where that column is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!

It show all those invoice A.INV_Nr which is not exist in table CANCEL_INVOICE

```
  SELECT INV_Nr, INV_Date, INV_Customer
  FROM INVOICE A, 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CANCEL_INVOICE B ON A.INV_Nr=B.INV_Nr
  WHERE B.INV_Nr IS NULL
```